# md5sum output only hash in file

Tags: bash, md5, md5sum

hi I want to create a bash file on linux, which checks the md5 hash of a file against a backup md5 hash, so i know if the original file has been tampered with. The script should output the md5 hash of two files and than compare the two created hash files:

```
md5sum file1 > file1.md5 | cut -c -32
if [ file1.md5 =! backup.md5 ] then;
   #send email
```

but it does not work, there is still the filename in the file.md5, has someone an idea on how to only get the has to the file.md5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues with your script.

First you apply `cut -c -32` *after* you have redirected the md5sum output to file1.md5 already, which is why it does nothing.

You should restructure it like that, instead:

```
md5sum file1 | cut -c -32 > file1.md5
```

Next, you can not really compare files with `=!` directly, you have to read and compare their content instead, like this:

```
[ "$(cat file1.backup.md5)" != "$(cat file1.real.md5)" ]
```

Also note that `md5sum` does already have a "check mode", so you can simply do this:

```
#Save MD5 sum of your file to backup.md5, in md5sum native format
md5sum file1 > backup.md5

#Later on ...
if ! md5sum -c backup.md5; then
...
```

Comment: thanks, the check mode didn't work, because i always copy the file to a different location before creating the md5 hash, so i can be sure, that it is not encrypted

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong order of the commands. Write the

```
md5sum file1 | cut -c -32 > file1.md5
```

Answer (score 1):

Re: "there is still the filename in the `md5` [string], ... how to only get the hash?"

The string that `md5sum` returns is (or at least is structured like) a record with two fields or a tuple with two elements. E.g.,

`$ md5sum filename.txt 
8d7dd71ff51614e69339b03bd1cb86ac  filename.txt`

To grab only the hash (the first field/element), try piping the string to awk like so:

`$ md5sum filename.txt | awk '{print $1}'
8d7dd71ff51614e69339b03bd1cb86ac`

I submit this answer to this specific part of OP's question asked over a year ago for others who are working on similar issues and stumble upon this thread as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe is in wrong position.Use like this:

```
 md5sum file1| cut -c -32 > file1.md5
```

Or for full implementation without saving md5 sums to files:

```
ORG_SUM=`md5sum org_file | cut -c -32`
BCK_SUM=`md5sum bck_file | cut -c -32`
if [ "${ORG_SUM}" != "${BCK_SUM}" ]; then
   #send email
fi
```